# Remove borders from form and increase size

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to know how to increase the size of an input field in height, give it a small inset shadow on selection and to remove the borders of said form. My default form is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/3gV89/).

My default form in, if you prefer to stay on this page:

```
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: You should be using `<label>`s for that text and try not using `<br>` tags for positioning.

Comment: You can write your desired styles in `input:focus{}` like `input:focus {box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that with form you mean the input fields in the form. To modify the apperance of the input fields in your form you should use css. E.g;

```
input { /* Select what you want to style */
 width: 200px; /* This modifies the width of the selected element. */
 height: 40px; /* This modifies the height */
 border: none; /* This removes the borders */
}

/**
 * To modify the input apperance on selection we need to use the focus psuedo selector.
 */
input:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) inset; /* This adds an inner shadow on the element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
form{
  height: 120%;/*apply in pixels as you need*/
  border: 5px inset #f00;
}
```

For what you are looking after is to use jQuery solution:

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
  $(this).closest('form').css({border:'5px inset #f00'});
});
```

[edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gV89/11/)

---

Since you updated your question: you want to apply in input fields then use like this:

```
input:focus{
  border: 5px inset #f00;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gV89/12/)

Comment: Hehe, what I actually meant was the input fields! But thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give it a fixed `height` value, as it will auto-increase based on the contents. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3gV89/2/

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: Yeah, I would really like that. Is it possible?

Comment: Edited the question to show that I meant the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using s for that text and try not using 
 
remove glow and borders

```
borders: none;
outline: none;
```

input fields, you can specify a class in which to specify the desired properties like this

```
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="mail" value="your email">

.input-field {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         inset 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    width: 250px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    height: 120%;
    border:0px ;
}
```